# How do I know the size of the background image for variable-height content?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I couldn't think of a good title, apologies.

I'm designing a personal website that has 4 sections inside a main. Inside each section is a title and a grid. The background of each section is a picture. I'm taking really large images and cropping them to the right aspect ratio, scaling them, and then assigning them to the appropriate section.

Currently, I'm designing for mobile but I'm sure the problem is ubiquitous across screen sizes. My problem is that when I set an images width and height, and then move to check on a different device (iPhone X to Pixel XL, for example), there is a space at the bottom of the section after the background image. This is because the image is too short.

I thought about making the image tall enough to accommodate the tallest device, but I ran into this problem: The content isn't always the tallest on the largest device. So I suppose this boils down to:

```
How do I know how large to make my images?
```

Do I have to look at the dimensions of the content on every device and pick the largest? There's gotta be a better way, right? The reason I don't want to just scale the image to 100% of the background is for fidelity (it makes a difference!).

Hope this is enough info, if it's not I'll be around. Thanks!

**Edit for clarification:**

Perhaps I wasn't clear. I'll be using media queries for the larger screen sizes, where I'll use larger images. Here's an example to clarify:

Suppose my first break-point is up to 568px. There are a range of devices under this value. However, just because they fall into the same break-point doesn't mean they have the same height and width.

Let's say device A has width 320px and height 600px, and device B has width 400px and height 650px. On device A, the first section of my website is 320px wide and 800px tall. On device B, the first section of my website is 400px wide and 750px tall.

I could make an image that is 400px wide and 800px tall, and this would satisfy the background conditions for both devices. However, I can't practically go through every device that exists to find the largest width for a particular section and the largest height for a particular section. I also can't be sure that my content won't change, in which case I would have to repeat the process.

Is there a way to do this without losing the quality of the image, without cutting out content, and with keeping reasonably the same padding and margins around elements? Or maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way?

Hope that helps clarify it. Thanks for the answers I've already received!

**Edit for solution:**
Ended up setting the size of each section manually. Messes with my spacing a bit but now I know the height and width across all devices under my breakpoint, as it will be the same.

Comment: Have you tried Media Rules inside your CSS? Ill post an answer as an example.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this purely through CSS thanks to the `background-size` property now in CSS3. We'll use the `html` element (better than `body` as it's always at least the height of the browser window). We set a fixed and centered background on it, then adjust it's size using `background-size` set to the cover keyword.

```
html { 
  background: url(XXX) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Note: Copy your URL into the `XXX` area, for example: `images/bg.jpg`. Then copy and paste the above into your CSS stylesheet.

Works in:
- Safari 3+
- Chrome Whatever+
- IE 9+
- Opera 10+
- Firefox 3.6+

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is right. +1. I see a lot of answers (and questions) using vendor prefixes and I don't understand why. The `background-size` CSS property has been supported in all browsers since 2011. Which browsers are we aiming to support from 2010? See: https://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this with @Media Queries in your CSS.

If its a larger screen--say a computer. You can have your normal CSS showing your background image. As the screen size changes, and you notice at a certain screen size (Like a phone screen) the image doesn't look right, you can add a media query to your CSS that looks something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("IMAGEURL.jpg");
  }
}
```

On devices that are equal to or smaller than the max-width of 600px the CSS will override your main CSS. This is how Responsive websites are built all the time. You can have as many Media queries as you would like. And there are other ways you can write the media queries. Hope this answers your question!

Check out this tutorial Found Here at W3schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: This is a long clarification so I'm going to put it in the post body :)